# After bringing my app to front, ShowMessage throws exception "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

Tags: android, delphi

I use Delphi 10.3 and want to bring my android app to front when some text is received from the host and show this text to the user with ShowMessage.

I tried to use TAndroidHelper.Activity.getFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions; before I call ShowMessage(RecText); but that doesn't change anything.

```
var
  RecText: String;

procedure TfoMain.BringAppToFront;
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setClassName(MainActivity.getPackageName, MainActivity.getClass.getName);
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
  Intent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  Intent.addFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.getBaseContext.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

After receiving the text from the host I use the following code:

```
  BringAppToFront;
  Sleep(100);
  ShowMessage(RecText);
```

My app is brought to front, but when it calls ShowMessage(RecText); the exception "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" is thrown and no message is shown.
When my app was in front before calling BringAppToFront, ShowMessage(RecText); shows the text correctly without any exception.

Comment: My understanding is that this code isn't going to do what you want it to do. Try a different approach. Android is a "user-oriented" device. Present a clickable notification message to the user, and let them bring the app to the foreground. That however, is also not a simple-block-of-code matter. Such is the nature of Android development.

Comment: Please provide a complete example of how to reproduce the issue, since your example on its own does not. Once that has been established, perhaps a solution can be suggested.

Comment: I solved the problem using a frame showing the message instead of calling ShowMessage.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me. In my case I made use of application events, monitoring for BecameActive, before executing the ShowMessage. Android has a problem with apps attempting to show a dialog when they're not the one in focus ;-)